# How to detect a blank input for a date in Shiny

Tags: r, date, shiny

I have a series of inputs in my R Shiny app that I am using as arguments to a function to select specific data from a data frame. On of the inputs is dateInput:

`dateInput("dateSelect", "Date", format = "yyyy-mm-dd", value = NA)`

In my function, I need to specify if dateSelect is blank or not selected, to be able select All dates. See an example that is working correctly, that isn't a date, and a simple selectInput:

`selectInput("teamSelect", "Team", choices = c("All", levels(newEffortstable$team)))`

In the function, this works to select 'All teams':

```
    if(!missing(teamSelect)){
    if(teamSelect!="All"){
    selections[["teamEfforts"]] = 
    newEffortstable$effortNo[which(newEffortstable$team %in% teamSelect)]
    }else{
    selections[["teamEfforts"]] = newEffortstable$effortNo
    }
    }
```

I have tried the following with `NA` and `NULL` and `" "` and keep getting 'Error in if: argument is of length zero'

```
    if(!missing(dateSelect)){
    if(!dateSelect== "NA"){
    selections[["dateEfforts"]] = 
    newEffortstable$effortNo[which(newEffortstable$date == dateSelect)]
    }else{
    selections[["dateEfforts"]] = newEffortstable$effortNo
    }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: check the functions `validate`, `need` and the concepts of `truthy` and `falsy` in shiny.

Comment: Thank you. I have read into these, but I'm not sure they do want I need... I need to be able to check if dateSelect is empty or null (i.e., if a user deletes the date from dateInput, and wants to select all dates)... And then use this argument to select the relevant data I need from a data frame?

Comment: I've added an answer illustrating how to figure out what you need and how to use the function `isTruthy`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's one option you didn't try out yet: checking the length. When no date is given, `dateInput` returns an empty `Date` vector as illustrated in the example below.

So you could check `if(length(input$dateSelect) == 0)`, but this is not the most solid shiny option. In order to avoid that you have to check all possibilities (i.e. `NULL`, `NA`, `""`, `numeric(0)` etc), you can use the function `isTruthy()` as in the example below:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dateInput("dateSelect","Date"),
    verbatimTextOutput("out"),
    textOutput("text")
  ),
  server = function(input,output,session){

    output$text <- renderText({
      if(!isTruthy(input$dateSelect)){
        "NO DATE"
      } else {
        paste("The chosen date is:",input$dateSelect)
      }
    })
    output$out<- renderPrint({str(input$dateSelect)})
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think to check length... That works. But I will take your advice to check all possibilities in Shiny and use the isTruthy function - does the job too. Thanks!